# Adding a custom subject field to the Revision Information Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I would like to be able to add a subject field to the Revision Information along with the log message. Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach:
You could extend the node_revision table with a new column that holds the revision log's title and modify the node edit form to capture the value for this field. Below is a little module example that does the trick. If you need some more help, let me know, cheers!

```
<?php

/*
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function raks_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if( isset($form['revision_information']) ){

    // Check the revision log checkbox when the log subject or textarea is filled in.
    // This must not happen if "Create new revision" is enabled by default, since
    // the state would auto-disable the checkbox otherwise.
    if (isset($form_state['node']) && !$form_state['node']->revision) {
      $form['revision_information']['revision']['#states'] = array(
        'checked' => array(
          array('input[name="log_subject"]' => array('empty' => FALSE)),
          array('textarea[name="log"]' => array('empty' => FALSE)),
        ),
      );
    }

    $form['revision_information']['log_subject'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',   
      '#title' => 'Revision log subject',
      '#weight' => -15,
      '#description' => t('Provide an subject for the changes you are making.'),
    );

    // Reorder / Move the checkbox above the new form field
    $form['revision_information']['revision']['#weight'] = $form['revision_information']['log_subject']['#weight'] - 1;
  }
}

/*
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function raks_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['node_revision']['fields']['log_subject'] = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'default' => null,
    'description' => "The subject of the revision log's description",
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  );
}

/*
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function raks_install() {
  if (!db_field_exists('node_revision', 'log_subject')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema('node_revision');
    db_add_field('node_revision', 'log_subject', $schema['fields']['log_subject']);
  }
}

/*
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function raks_uninstall() {
  if (db_field_exists('node_revision', 'log_subject')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema('node_revision');
    db_drop_field('node_revision', 'log_subject');
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function raks_views_api()
{
    return array(
        'api' => 3
    );
}
```

You would also need a separate *.views.inc file, e.g. raks.views.inc, with the following code inside:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function raks_views_data_alter(&$data)
{

  $data['node_revision']['log_subject'] = array(
    'title' => "Subject of the revision's log",
    'help' => "Subject of the revision's log",
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE, // This is use by the table display plugin.
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    )
  );

}
```

Once this file is in place (and following a clear-cache if needed), you should have access to the log_subject as a field in your Content Revisions view.

Let me know if this works all the way, I am curious :-)
May even submit it as a contrib module on D.O., what do you think?

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I am also trying to display the revisions via the views module. Do you know how I can pull in that newly created field, and display it on the page?

Comment: Welcome! I updated the answer with infos about how to get this working with Views. Cheers

Comment: I think its a good idea. This definitely helped with my project. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

No - because revisions are not [Drupal entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744) themselves but metadata associated with entities. You can expose an [entity to the revisioning system](https://www.drupal.org/node/1892478) but not the other way around, its [a core part of Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/1892478).

Best way I could think of to come close to this functionality is to have a special fieldset / field collection of fields that allow for what you want (ex. log message, subject) and then use field permissions to hide that from the end user. You would then have your team use these fields for recording their updates rather than the log field.